# Jquery UI button CSS issue in fire fox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I am using firefox 11.0
on this page http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/
I am seeing some miss aligned (vertically) button like image below
[image]

In chrome there is no issue.
I have upgraded firefox using the same version setup for a repair install.
But this does not fix issue.

Please check and tell me, do u face this issue..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are `inline-block` elements so there default value is **basline** .write `vertical-align: top;` in your `ui-corner-all`. Write like this:

```
.ui-corner-all{
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: don't u think. this might misaligned some elements where I manually apply `ui-corner-all` class.

Comment: then you can write inside button,input like this button,input{vertical-align: top;}

Answer (score 2):

Yes, firefox has that behaviour. It defaults to vertical align: baseline for a tags, so to fix it, you can apply a style vertical-align: top to the a tag (anchor), that way it will be displayed in line with the other 2 buttons

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i see it too.... remove `overflow:hidden;` from the ui-button class.

Comment: I do not manage Jquery UI website. How can I update their css.
So this is a bug with firefox. not this..??

Comment: You can't update their CSS. It's a quirk with firefox, try the suggestions and see for yourself.